# Sharing the same templates by importing PHP files: Where should I store those PHP files?

Tags: theming

I want to be able to just edit standard PHP files which are then imported into many themes.

I feel like a module is an overkill, so I'm happy with just a folder of files.

Comment: A base theme that all the others inherit from would make most sense IMO. That’s about the only “Drupal” way of approaching it if you don’t want a module. But your mileage may vary, it depends what you need to achieve, how you’re going to go about deployment/updates/etc

Comment: I've gone too far with my themes and I have two of them to worry about. I'd rather just have separate tpl files.

Comment: There’s no Drupal best-practice in that case, just do what works best for your exact requirements

Comment: Ok, thanks. And I found the module domain_themekey which works perfectly for my use-case along with importing php files.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states "*I feel like a module is an overkill*", but (according to your own comment) the [Domain ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_themekey) module works perfectly for your use-case along with importing php files.

Some details about this module (from its project page):

> Integration of Domain Access and ThemeKey.
>
> Module provides additional ThemeKey properties:
>
> - domain:site_name - returns current domain's site name
> - domain:id - returns current domain's id
> - domain:machine_name - returns current domain's machine name
> - domain:is_default - returns true if current domain configured as default domain
> - domain:is_alias - returns true if system:host is an alias for current domain

Comment: Well that module deals with a problem I hadn't considered when I posted the question. (And I deleted the comment that explained the problem: Two themes based on role have to be duplicated many times). Anyways, the problem is solved now.